# Procedure is unable to find function since it is defined after the procedure, how to fix this?

Tags: vhdl

In my VHDL entity, I have declared some procedures in the header of the architecture i.e before the keyword `begin`. Some procedures are calling functions. The functions are actually defined in a block after the block that define the procedures. When I compile the code, I get `"Unknown identifier"` error.

I could just move the function definitions above the procedure definitions i.e cut paste the block of code or just shift it up in the source file. However, there must be a better way around this.

How do I write the code so the procedure knows that the function it is trying to call is actually defined after the procedure definition?

Comment: Move the functions into a package and "use" the package.all  in the entity declaring the procedures. It's anotehr way of putting them in scope.

Comment: You can keep the functions definitions as it is, and instead add only the function prototypes above the procedures (no body/definition). For e.g: `function xyz (<arguments>) return <return_type> ;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the functions are defined in blocks inside the body of the entity (between the keywords "begin" and "end") then they are not in scope in the declarative part of the entity (between the keywords "is" and "begin") where you are defining the procedures.

You need to move the function declarations into scope somehow.  The most obvious way would be to put them in the declarative part of the entity declaration before the procedure declarations.

```
entity foo is 

end entity;

architecture bar of foo is 
--declare functions here
--declare procedures here
begin

    X:block
    --don't declare functions here because procedures can't see them. 
    begin

    end block X;

end bar;
```

I don't see any way to solve this other than to move the function declarations into scope at the point where the procedures are declared.

You could alternatively try defining the functions in a package an then referencing the package with a statement like "use work.my_package.all".

Comment: oh, I did not mean the VHDL keyword "block". hmm

Comment: +1 for the package, I think that's the most proper approach and allows reuse in other entities without multiple definition of the same function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't, sadly.

There's no such thing as forward declaration of functions outside of packages. It's a bit strange because the declaration <> body split in packages makes it seem as if the same split should work in other places, but it doesn't.

Your two solutions are to move the functions in front of the procedures or split them off in a separate package which you use. But the full function has to be defined before using it.